# iterating through ls output is not occurring in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to `ls` the directories and print them out but nothing is being displayed. I am able to `SSH` and execute the first pwd. However, anything within the the for loop has no output. I know for sure there are directories called `event-test-` because I've done so manually. I've manually entered the directory (`/data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/`) and ran this piece of code and the correct output appeared so I'm not sure why

manually entered has correct output:

```
for i in `ls | grep "event-test"`; do echo $i; done;
```

script:

```
for h in ${hosts[*]}; do
        ssh -i trinity-prod-keypair.pem bc2-user@$h << EOF
                sudo bash
                cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/

                pwd
                for i in `ls | grep "event-test-"`; do
                        pwd
                        echo $i;
                done;
                exit;
                exit;

EOF

done
```

Comment: Which user should execute `cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/`? root or bc2-user?

Comment: @Cyrus I want to execute on bc2user

Comment: okay. `sudo bash`, all trailing `;` and all `exit` are useless.

Answer (score 3):

It is because

```
`ls | grep "event-test-"`
```

is executing on your localhost not on remote host. Besides parsing `ls` is error prone and not even needed. You can do:

```
for h in "${hosts[@]}"; do
   ssh -t -t trinity-prod-keypair.pem bc2-user@$h <<'EOF'
   sudo bash
   cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/
   pwd
   for i in *event-test-*; do
       pwd
       echo "$i"
   done
  exit
  exit
EOF
done
```

Comment: how do you type that dot? What does it mean?

Comment: I suppose that this is a typo and should be `*` to glob all files which contain string `event-test-`.

Comment: Sorry for typo, it was supposed to be `*` on either side for globbing

Comment: Getting this error: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Comment: That is a warning, see updated answer. You need to use `ssh -t -t`

Answer (score 1):

When parsing ls it is good practice to do `ls -1` to get a prettier list to parse. Additionally, when trying to find files named "event-test-" I would recommend the find command. Since I am not completely sure what you are attempting to do other than list the locations of these "event-test" files I'd recommend something more similar to the following:

```
for h in "${hosts[@]}"; do ssh trinity-prod-keypair.pem bc2-user@$h -t -t "find /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/ -type f -name *event-test-*;" ; done
```

This will give you a pretty output of the full path to the file and the file name.

I hope this helps.